# Testing .NET 7 AOT Lambda Function Locally with Visual Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-7.0, aot

I'm working on a project that involves developing a **.NET 7** application that includes an **Ahead-of-Time (AOT)** compiled Lambda function. I'm using Visual Studio as my development environment. I would like to know if there is a way to test the AOT Lambda function locally within Visual Studio.
Is there a recommended approach or any tooling available that allows me to test AOT Lambda functions locally within Visual Studio? I want to verify the correctness and performance of the AOT-compiled code before deploying it to the AWS Lambda environment.

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to test using the Mock lambda test tool6.0 and I was unable to test with that, and I am expecting, is there any mock lambda test tool available for .NET7 AOT lambda function.